# modify last field of complete csv file

Tags: linux, shell, vi

I hava a csv(delimiter:commaseparated) file like this
a,b,c,d
There are approximate 10000 lines in csv file like above.
Whatever written at last field i have to change with 'e'.

Eg.
Input file

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
i,j,k,l
m,n,o,p
```

Output file

```
a,b,c,e
e,f,g,e
i,j,k,e
m,n,o,e
```

As you can see d(first line last element),h(second line last element),l(third line last element),p(fourth line last element)
...All are replaced by 'e'.

How can i change this by shell scripting on linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way using awk:

```
awk -F, '{$NF="e";}1' OFS=, file
```

`$NF` indicates the last field of the file. Just by setting "e" to $NF gets your job done. 1 is to print every line.

`-F` => to specify the input field separator,
`OFS` => to specify the o/p field separator

One more option using **sed**:

To change the file in place using GNU sed:

```
sed -i 's/\(.*,\).*/\1e/' file
```

sed matches the pattern till the last comma and groups it which is available is `\1`. By just appending "e", we get the solution.

Comment: Please can u more explain on this

Comment: Some expanding on the way `sed` detects the last comma would be great, please.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{ print $1, $2, $3, "e" }'
```

A shortcoming of this approach is that it assumes commas do not appear in the fields themselves.